# How to recover Excel VBA Module from a closed Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Office 365 file that immediately crashes upon opening.

The file contains VBA modules that do not have a backup. I would like to extract the VBA modules without opening the file.

Is there a way to read the contents of the VBA modules and save them for reuse in a new file?

Comment: Does it crash if you open Excel in safe mode?

Comment: https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools

Comment: http://www.ribboncommander.com/ can also help you repair problems associated with corrupted Excel files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to Bigben , i opened excel in safe mode and was able to recover my code modules.
Although it does not answer the question i originally posed ie: is there a way to read the modules without opening the file", it achieves the same intent. Thank you BigBen

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I had a similar issue with a corrupt word template (Normal.dotm) with my macros.  The way I salvaged my code was by renaming the template from Normal.dotm to Normal.zip.  This allowed me to open it and view the structure.

Within the zip, there is a folder called 'word' and within this, it contained two files called vbaData.xml and vblProject.bin.  I copied these onto desktop.  Then, I created a new word template (Normal1.dotm), and created a dummy macro within it (not sure if this was a necessary step).

I then saved it, and renamed that Normal1.zip.  I then opened it and went into the 'word' folder and copied the two files from desktop (called vbaData.xml and vblProject.bin) into it.

I saved it, renamed it back to Normal1.dotm, and when I ran it, my code was back.

Hope this helps someone else - I presume it's a similar process for excel.

Comment: I was just wondering how to get text out of the .bin inside my recovered excel .zip file, when I saw your post. Brilliant! Just copy the bin from one file (the corrupt one) to the other (the recovered one).